# VF Page Custom Button to navigateToURL blanks out the screen

Tags: custom-button

Have my VFPage code as below. what am i doing wrong here

```
<apex:page standardController="Grading_Sample__c" recordSetVar="samples">
<apex:dataTable value="{!selected}" var="Sample">
    <apex:column >
        <apex:outputLabel styleClass="ids">{!Sample.Sample_Event_ID__c}</apex:outputLabel>
    </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
<style>
.ids{visibility : hidden}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
     var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    var tabId = result.id
     var redirectUrl = '{!$Setup.vitCalcProductionSettings__c.GrainSuite_URL__c}';
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        var elems = document.body.getElementsByClassName("ids");
        var ids = new Array();

        for (var i = elems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            ids[i] = elems[i].innerHTML;    
        }
        //console.log(ids);
        if (ids && ids.length > 1)
            {
            redirectUrl += 'Grading/SampleSummary/GeneratePdf?GradingSamples='+ids.join(',');            
            if (sforce && sforce.one && sforce.one.navigateToURL) { sforce.one.navigateToURL(redirectUrl);}
                sforce.one.back();
            }

        else
            {
            sforce.one.back();
            alert('Please select at least one record.');
            }
    });
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Please also include your issue/question in the body of your posts, rather than just in the titles. It often gets overlooked if only in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find it easier to do the redirect using Visualforce and PageReferences, but I think you're just calling `back()` before any other navigation happens, so if you're loading this page directly to test it I think you're just going back to your browser's default empty page view:

```
if (ids && ids.length > 1) {
    redirectUrl += 'Grading/SampleSummary/GeneratePdf?GradingSamples=' + ids.join(',');
    
    if (sforce && sforce.one && sforce.one.navigateToURL) {
        sforce.one.navigateToURL(redirectUrl);
    }
    sforce.one.back();
}
```

Reformatting this code makes it a little easier to see what's happening, but I suspect the call to `sforce.one.navigateToURL(redirectUrl);` gets done in the following event loop rather than immediately, and the subsequent call to `sforce.one.back()` might be clearing that? Speculation because I've not used those navigation methods myself for a very long time, but I'd suggest taking out the call to back and trying that.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the response. my response is in delay but apparently I followed the same approach to resolve this.